# Meaning of "Gambler at heart"

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

I want to know what does the expression `gambler at heart` mean and in which context we can use it?

Comment: What does the question title mean??

Comment: [at heart](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/at-heart?q=at+heart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say someone is something ***at heart*** means that they are that thing by their true nature. A ***gambler at heart*** is therefore someone who is naturally inclined to take risks or make bets.

I'd say *gambler at heart* is a fairly non-offensive description.